# Best way to access lists and nest them with if statements

Tags: python

Trying to improve my Python skills by creating a small text adventure. I have used lists to access certain information, but I am not sure if I am using them correctly. For instance, I have used a list to store weapons but wasn't sure of the syntax for accessing them in an if statement. Also, if there is any advice on how to improve the code in general that would be appreciated. I am a beginner so would prefer a simple alternative.

```python
weapon = ["sword", "stone", "flower"]  


# Create user defined functions for the game first.

def title():
    print("In front of you there is a portal. You have no idea where it leads")
    print("portal #1")

# Call function

title()
portal = input("Type 1: ")

if portal == "1":
    print("There's a wizard conjuring a spell.")
    print("What do you do?")
    print("1. Talk to the wizard.")
    print("2. Attack the wizard.")
    print("3. Run away.")
    
    choice_wizard = input("Type 1,2,3: ")
    
    if choice_wizard == "1":
        print("The wizard turns you into a frog. Ribbit!")

    elif choice_wizard == "2":
        print("You see a sword laying on the ground")
        print("Would you like to take the sword? Press y or n to continue")
    
        weapon_input = input("Type y or n: ")
        if weapon_input == "y" or weapon_input == "Y":
            weapon = []
            weapon.append("sword")
            print("You are now carrying a " + weapon[0] + ", You kill the wizard")
        elif weapon_input == "n" or weapon_input == "N":
            weapon = []
            weapon.append("stone")
            print("You are now carrying a " + weapon[0] + ", You hit the wizard in the head with it")
            print("He falls over unconscious and dies")           
    elif choice_wizard == "3":
        print("The wizard tries turning you into a frog but misses.")
        print("...You escape.")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are just a few comments to help improve your code:

1. When you have a collection, think about how you are going to access the collection. Most of the time, you are going to treat it as a group of items (example: "weapons") and so you should use a plural name. Rarely, you will treat a collection as a single item (example: "database"), and so you should use a singular name.
2. **Always** use functions. Yes, python supports having statements directly "up against the wall." But it is much, much easier to write test cases, to debug your code, and to change your mind about what order to do things if you have a single name (function) for a group of statements. Moving things around as blobs of text is miserable and prone to errors.
3. When you find yourself doing something twice, **write a function!** In your case, asking the user for some input is a good place to put a function:

   ```
    show_message("There's a wizard conjuring a spell.")
    choice = get_choice("What do you do?",
          "Talk to the wizard",
          "Attack the wizard",
          "Run away")
   ```
4. As far as your collection of `weapons` is concerned, think about what kind of game you are writing. If you are writing a "dungeon" style game, where there is going to be a lot of fighting monsters, then having real weapon-objects with stats will be important. In that case, you'll probably want either a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set) or a `list`, but you'll want a separate variable to track which of the possibly many weapons is currently being wielded.

   On the other hand, if you are writing more of a "text adventure" game, where just having "the sword" is enough to beat a monster, then you might not want a collection at all. Instead, you might want one or more boolean variables, or perhaps a dictionary full of booleans.

```
      if user_has['the sword']:
          show_message("The troll runs away!")
      else:
          show_message("The troll eats you. You have died.")
```

5. To specifically answer your question about how to access members of lists: note that you are using the `list.append()` function. This takes an object and adds it to the *end of the list*. So if you have 11 items in the list, and you `.append` another item, it will be the 12th item (index 11, because list indexes are 0-based).

   You can access that item in two ways. The "hard way" is to compute the length of the list and subtract one:

   ```
    item = "sword"
    weapons.append(item)
    sword_index = len(weapons) - 1
    print("You have a", weapons[sword_index])
   ```

   An easier way is to reply on the fact that python supports negative indexes as being from the end of the list. That is, `list[-1]` is the last item, `list[-2]` is the next-to-last item, etc. This works with indexes *and* with slices, so you can also say `list[1:-3]` or `list[-5:]` for example. See note 3 in the [`sequence docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ranges#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) for details.

Comment: If `show_message` is just a renaming of `print` it does not seem to be necessary. Ideally `show_message` should provide some extra functionality, e.g. print multiple messages on multiple lines in one statement.

Comment: @GZ0 I think `show_message` is there to be extensible. for eg. when/if OP decides to build a GUI, adds logging etc. and not necessarily restricted to just `print`

Comment: @GZ0 The intent behind `show_message` is to do whatever is needed for the game. Maybe put some color escape sequences, maybe draw a pop-up dialog box, maybe handle i18n, maybe copy the message to a log file. I want to encourage @op to create a comfortable set of primitives that express what the application needs, rather than what the standard library provides.

Answer (score 1):

Some general comments about your approach, not too much specific to your code:

If you are going to do text interaction look at the [cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html#module-cmd) module which will give you a structure for the part of your code where you interact with the user.  Group all your I/O in an Interaction class that passes commands to the rest of your program.  One of the advantages of doing so is that you can do automated testing on the rest of the program - look at the [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) module for a simple test framework.

You should look to making the structure of your adventure separate from the code that implements the actions that can be taken.  You have locations (nodes), actors (positioned on a node, possibly able to move, modifying or adding to the description of the location), choices (links to other nodes, descriptions of the choices are part of the node's description), loot and weapons (A kind of actor which can be attached to the adventurer), and the adventurer themselves (has at least inventory and position, possibly other attributes that can modify results of choices).

These can each be implemented as classes with instances for each `Location` in the map, `Choice`s get attached to `Location`s, in game characters (`Actors`) get attached to a `Location` instance, etc.  Now selecting a `Choice` can modify the `Adventurer`'s `Location` and entering (setting) a new `Location` prints out the location description.  Part of the location description is the description of each of the choices attached to the `Location` and each of the `Actor`s currently attached to the `Location`.  This "attachment" is just a list of objects of the appropriate type.

```
for num,choice in enumerate(adventurer.location.choices):
    print(f"{num}: choice.desc"})
choicenum = inp("What do you do")
```

and now when the user enters a number that `Choice`'s instance is found at `adventurer.location.choices[choicenum]`.

I would also suggest that you start with a simplified version and then add complexity.  In particular I think that defining the nodes and links and then just being able to wander around would be a good base to build from.  This would require just the Adventurer, Location and Choice classes along with your Interaction class where all the I/O would take place.

Good luck, this sounds like it may be a fun project.